# optimal number of knots in GAM

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, smoothing, splines

I constructed a model of the form:

```
mdl.gam<-gam(sqrt(y) ~ s(x1,fx=FALSE,k=-1,bs="cs")+s(x2,fx=FALSE,k=-1,bs="cs")+
        s(x3,fx=FALSE,k=-1,bs="cs")+s(x4,fx=FALSE,k=-1,bs="cs")+ 
        s(x5,fx=FALSE,k=-1,bs="cs")+s(x6,fx=FALSE,k=-1,bs="cs")+
        s(x7,fx=FALSE,k=-1,bs="cs")+s(x8,fx=FALSE,k=-1,bs="cs")+ 
        s(x9,fx=FALSE,k=-1,bs="cs") + s(x10,fx=FALSE,k=-1,bs="cs")+
        s(x11,fx=FALSE,k=-1,bs="cs") + s(x12,fx=FALSE,k=-1,bs="cs"),  
        data = data)
```

The error message I get is:

```
Error in smooth.construct.cr.smooth.spec(object, data, knots) : 
x9 has insufficient unique values to support 10 knots: reduce k.
```

I have two questions:

1) Isn't the the option `fx=FALSE, k = -1` supposed to determined optimal number of knots through cross validation? If yes, then I should not have an error saying x9 does not support 10 knots since number of knots is being determined by cross validation

2) `bs=cs` is fitting a cubic regression spline with shrinkage. Does it mean it will penalise the model for over-fitting and hence determined the optimal number of knots to fit in the model? How is it different from `bs=cr`?

Thanks

Comment: the `fx=FALSE` and `k=-1` are the default settings and do not need to be added https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/s.html. You should set your `k` to something relevant - typically df-1 - also set your gamma to 1.4 https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/mgcv/html/choose.k.html